# "ng-circle-progress" percent attribute only works when the renderOnClick attribute is set to true

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic4

I'm trying to add a Circle Progress Bar on my Ionic app. The progress bar is shown, but when the `renderOnClick` attribute is set to `false`, the progress bar doesn't automatically go to the `percent` value. It stays at `0%`.

I've tried setting the default value for `renderOnClick` and `percent` in the *home.module.ts* file and removing them too to see if that changed anything, but it didn't unfortunately.

Here is my circle-progress tag in the *home.page.html*:

```html
    <circle-progress
        [percent]="85"
        [radius]="100"
        [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
        [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
        [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
        [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
        [animation]="true"
        [animationDuration]="300">
    </circle-progress>
```

And here are my default values in *home.module.ts*:

```js
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      // these are default values if not defined
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#78c000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#c7e596",
      animationDuration: 300,
      animation: false,
      responsive: true,
      renderOnClick: true
    })
```

I'm expecting the progress bar to go from 0% to 85% (or whatever percentage is given) when the `renderOnClick` is set to false.

But it stays at 0%.

Comment: Any resolution found to this? I'm having the same issue now

Comment: @user9847788 - The accepted answer seems to work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by setting lazy: false i.e.

```
NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
  // these are default values if not defined
  lazy : false
})
```

Comment: ngcircle makes full when percent is 100. how to make it for 10. i have percentage out of 10 and make it full when value is 10. Any suggest